# Should `clamav-devel`, ` clamav-server-systemd`,`clamav-server` be installed if I only manual scan folder in one server?

Tags: clamav

In lots of `how to install clamav in centos 7`tutorial, all modules are installed,such like `yum install clamav-server clamav-data clamav-update clamav-filesystem clamav clamav-scanner-systemd clamav-devel clamav-lib clamav-server-systemd`.

I want to find answer in [Clamav official document](https://www.clamav.net/documents/faq-overview.md), but get 404 error.

I only want to manually use `clamav` to scan in one server like `clamscan -r /folder`,which module should be installed?

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to manually use clamav to scan in one server like clamscan
>   -r /folder

No, not everything is required if you just want to scan data. All you need is to use 2 pieces of ClamAV one is for scanning `clamav` and other is to update the signature `clamav-update`

```
yum install clamav clamav-update -y
```

Once done, then

`freshclam` to update the virus signature database.

`clamscan -r /folder` to scan the data.

See official documentation too [ClamavNet](https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav#rhel)